# Why there is a discrepancy in calculating power of a Matrix having complex numbers?

Tags: python, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to find the 6th power of the following 2 X 2 matrix having complex numbers:
A =

```
([[j, 0],   
  [1, -j]])
```

And the results differ when I do manually and using Python 3.7

When I do manually, I get -I (2 X 2), where as using Python, I got

```
[[-1.+0.j  0.+0.j]  
 [ 1.+0.j -1.-0.j]] , which are obviously not the same.
```

Can someone explain please, why this discrepancy is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the regular `**` operator, numpy will compute the power element-wise:

```python
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1j, 0],
              [1, -1j]])

print(A**6)
```

```
[[-1.+0.j  0.+0.j]
 [ 1.+0.j -1.+0.j]]
```

What we are looking for is `np.linalg.matrix_power` [1]

> For positive integers n, the power is computed by repeated matrix squarings and matrix multiplications.

```python
print(np.linalg.matrix_power(A, 6))
```

```
[[-1.+0.j  0.+0.j]
 [ 0.+0.j -1.+0.j]]
```

Which is the result to expect. [2]

---

[1] [Numpy Documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.matrix_power.html?highlight=matrix_power#numpy.linalg.matrix_power)

[2] [Calculation with Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%5B%5Bi%2C+0%5D%2C++++++%5B1%2C+-i%5D%5D%29**6)